# jquery ace editor namespace in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ace-editor, monospace

I am working with ace9 editor, and originally everything was perfect, but I just noticed since last weeks, the editor is not working correctly in google chrome, for Firefox or IE is fine, but not in chrome, I was reading and always seems the problem is related with the monospace font but I am trying to isolate the problem in a single example, and not able to fix it yet.

Ace9 and I am using the src folder without requireJS

https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about

Here is my code, if someone could see the way to fix it.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initializeAceEditor(){
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
        editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
        editor.setOptions({
            maxLines: 15,
            minLines: 15
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        initializeAceEditor();
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <label class="col-xs-12">Definition*
        <div id="editor" class="col-xs-12">
            function foo(items) {
                var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
                return x;
            }
        </div>
    </label>
</body>
```

Unforntunatelly i cant create a jsfiddle because i cant upload all required ace files.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps someone; finally the problem was not in the code, I had to modify the default fonts of the google chrome browser:

chrome://settings/fonts

Defining some fonts which are not Arial, and are monospace based, I set "Courier" as default and now the Ace editor is working correctly...